# How does Apple handle/identify reversed transactions by the user in the receipt?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Right now I'm verify the IAP receipt sent to me by Apple on my server. I iterate through the "in_app" section of the receipt, which holds the various purchases the user has made. "product_id" holds the "com.identifier.appname.sku" that I have. "quantity" holds the quantity of the purchase, etc.

What I'm wondering is, in the rare case the user reverses their transaction through Apple, does apple update this receipt section for the product sku to say "0". Or do they remove this part of the receipt all together?

If the former, what is the user purchases the product again later intentionally. Will there no be an entry for "product1" with quantity 0, and "product1" with quantity 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed breakup of each of the receipts fields - under which there is a **[Receipt Cancellation Date](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW19)**. You may want to check that part of the receipt - a non-null value would mean the transaction (or the original transaction) would have been reversed.